# Calling a variable from a nested function python

Tags: python, function, nested

Idea of the project is

1. Make random selection A and random selection B
2. Compare the follower_count from both of these data
3. If the answer is correct ..replace random selection A with the correct answer data and generate another random selection B (so if A is correct that means no need to change, only B need to change; and if B is correct it needs to replace and become the new A, generate a new B) . Repeat until answer is incorrect.
   stuck at the def game(). Help appreciated

   ```
    from art import logo, vs
    from data import data
    import random

    def selection_a():
        a = random.choice(data)
        print(f"Compare A: {a.get('name')}, a {a.get('description')}, from 
        {a.get('country')}")

        def followers_a():
            num_of_followers_a = a.get('follower_count')
            print(num_of_followers_a)
            return num_of_followers_a
        followers_a()
        return a

    def selection_b():
        b = random.choice(data)
        print(f"Against B: {b.get('name')}, a {b.get('description')}, from 
        {b.get('country')}")

        def followers_b():
             num_of_followers_b = b.get('follower_count')
            print(num_of_followers_b)
            return num_of_followers_b
        followers_b()
        return b    

     def game():
           end_game = False

           selection_a()
           print(vs)
           selection_b()

           followers_a
           followers_b

           while not end_game:

                answer = input("Who has more followers? Type 'A' or 'B': ").upper()

                current_score = 0

                if answer == "A":
                   if followers_a > followers_b:
                      current_score += 1
                      print(f"You are right! Current score: {current_score}")
                      selection_a()

                   else:
                      print(f"Sorry, that's wrong, Final score: {current_score}")
                       end_game = True

               elif answer == "B":
                    if followers_b > followers_a:
                        current_score += 1
                        print(f"You are right! Current score: {current_score}")
                        selection_b()
                    else:
                       print(f"Sorry, that's wrong, Final score: {current_score}")
                       end_game = True

               else:
                  print("invalid entry, type again")

    game()
   ```

Comment: You say you're "stuck at the def game()" - how exactly are you stuck? What is the specific problem you're having?

Comment: @Grismar ,,in the game()....trying to call the nested function followers_a() (and b) which returns the follower count , so that the if statements can be executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first set the results of your functions to variables.

```py
    selected_data_a = selection_a()
    selected_data_b = selection_b()
    followers_a = selected_data_a.get('follower_count')
    followers_b = selected_data_b.get('follower_count')
```